# Какие возможности языка Rust нельзя использовать при написании своей библиотеки?

Tags: dll, rust, библиотека

Например: можно ли использовать макросы в коде написанной библиотеки?

Comment: Тэг dll вызывает подозрение, что под "библиотекой" может подразумеваться что-то более специфическое, чем библиотечный крейт rust.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Мне известны всего несколько специальных механизмов языка, которые нельзя использовать в коде библиотечных крейтов без ограничений на общую компоновку программы. Это глобальные символы, такие как функция `main`, [глобальный аллокатор](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/platform-and-target-support/global-allocators.html) или [обработчик паник](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/runtime.html#the-panic_handler-attribute).

Есть возможности, которыми можно, но не рекомендуется пользоваться в библиотеках. Из наиболее часто встречающихся анти-паттернов можно отметить скрытую ленивую инициализацию глобальных или поточно-локальных объектов (с помощью `Once`, `lazy_static!`, `thread_local!` и т.п.) с нетривиальными эффектами на поведении программы. Как пример, async-std скрытно инициализирует для вас свой глобальный движок исполнения async задач на пуле потоков, если вы воспользуетесь библиотекой, использующей асинхронную функциональность из async-std, даже если вы об этой детали реализации ничего не знаете. В tokio это сделано лучше: библиотека не инициализирует `Runtime` скрытно, но вызывает панику, если какой-либо из ее асинхронных примитивов используются вне контекста `Runtime`.

Наконец, есть тип крейта `cdylib`, предназначенный для создания динамически загружаемых библиотек с C-совместимым ABI. В *публичном* интерфейсе таких крейтов могут быть только функции `extern "C"`; также есть рекомендованные ограничения на типы данных в параметрах и возвращаемых значениях таких функций, например, структурные типы должны иметь атрибут `repr(C)`. В остальном коде библиотеки типа `cdylib` можно пользоваться всеми возможностями языка, включая макросы, и стандартными библиотеками.